# Can InnoDB limit CHAR by byte length?

Tags: database, types, innodb

I need to store entries in the range of billions, so row real estate is pretty precious here. There is a short string for every entry with the following spec:

- Up to 20 characters in 1-byte UTF8 range
- Up to 10 characters in 4-byte UTF8 range
- Total byte length <= 50

I'd like to do something like CHAR(50) in InnoDB with utf8mb4 as charset, except that the 50 means byte-length not character-length. Is this possible? I'd prefer the data remain legible, but this is not a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Use `VARCHAR(20)`.  That allows *up to* 20 utf8mb4 *characters*.  I suggest you use a number a little larger than 20, just in case the specifications change later.  Your first two bullet items would take "up to" 21 and 41 *bytes*, respectively.  The "1" is for the "length".

Back to `CHAR`.  It is "fixed" length.  And it refers to *characters*.  That is `CHAR(20)` utf8mb4 is always 80 bytes.  Well, not always.  InnoDB silently changes it to a hybrid between fixed- and variable-length.  Let's not go into that mess.

It is good to try to conserve space.  Be sure to do likewise with the various `INTs`.

Alas, InnoDB takes 2x-3x the space that you might predict.  This overhead is necessary for (1) handling ACID, and (2) speed efficiency.

**More**

"Word" alignment is not useful -- The code is too generic to take any advantage of such.  [VAR]BINARY counts bytes; it does not character set checks, so it is "faster".  The "VAR" takes one byte, but saves in that the string, itself, may be shorter than the max.

For `VAR`, there is no difference between (20), (40), (50), etc, with two exceptions.  The max is checked when inserting, and beyond some point, there needs to be 2 bytes for the "length".

Show us the variety of data that you will be storing as strings.  We may be able to advise in more detail.  For example, the accented letters of western Europe take 1 byte with character set latin1, but 2 bytes in utf8.  VARBINARY would blindly take whatever the client gives it -- with no understanding or conversion of the encoding.

Since you mentioned "4-byte", I infer that you must use `VARCHAR(...), CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` and the max needs to the max number of *characters*, not *bytes*.  Switching to `VARBINARY(...)` gives you no change in the space required.  However, the max needs to be in *bytes*.  Based on your specs, it sounds like either of these would suffice and take an identical amount of disk space:

```
VARCHAR(20)  -- but make that a little bigger, just in case
VARBINARY(50)  -- ditto
```

Have you also checked all the numeric columns?  Many people blindly use 4-byte INT or 8-byte BIGINT when they don't need such a big range.  Similarly for FLOAT/DOUBLE and DECIMAL.

Comment: Would BINARY or VARBINARY work here? I'm coming too close to the engine's hard limits for comfort. I'm also interested in whether aligning rows to 8-byte multiples has any noticeable effect on performance or storage.

Comment: @AranSumishii - I added More.

Comment: Thanks. On numeric columns, I have an ID autoincrement for PK, but INT is too close to the data limit (10^9), so I'm resorting to BIGINT, unless there's a way to do something like 6-byte integers?

Comment: @AranSumishii - Alas, no.  `BIGINT` is necessary there.  Unless...  There is some "natural" PK that could be used instead.  Would you care to share `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and say whether other tables JOIN to this table on `id`?

Comment: @AranSumishii - an example of such: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_sensor#indexing  (that blog is not yet finished)

Comment: Thanks for the blog link, that was really helpful! There are no plans to JOIN this table on anything, and ID is there just for maintenance ease (from your blog, probably means I should use a unique key with hotspots for efficiency). But I digress, you've answered my main question.